# Deploying a development version of a shiny app to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

I developed an app that I have deployed to shinyapps.io. It's been decided that there should be two deployed versions - one for testing purposes, and one stable release. Is there any way to do this via RStudio GUI or the command line?

Comment: I use RStudio Connect, not shinyapps.io, but it should be close enough ... we use the same code-base, but choose `appName="MyApp"` or `appName="MyApp_dev"` at push-time.

Comment: Thanks! If you write this comment as an answer I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no way to have one app installed with both a production and development version. I use RStudio Connect (should be similar enough to shinyapps.io), and we push to two different apps with similar names. That is, one might use each of the following depending on your updates:

```r
rsconnect::deployApp(..., appName="MyApp")
rsconnect::deployApp(..., appName="MyApp_dev")
```

While I think it would be awesome to have a feature that "copies app A over app B" so that, when ready, you could just copy `"MyApp_dev"` over `"MyApp"` automatically, but ... I can't see that feature being incredibly useful all the time, so once we've confirmed that the dev version is sufficient, we push the code to `"MyApp"` without any updates from the dev code.